# Javascript: object return itself a.k.a. chaining

Tags: javascript

I am **trying to** build my own little jquery-like library but I'm having a really rough time with creating this chaining pattern. Basically I have one class with a bunch of methods that make it easier to manipulate the document. Here's an example

```
function MF(selector){
    var DO; // Stands for DocumentObject
    this.select = function(selector){
        return document.getElementById(selector);
    }
    if(typeof selector === 'string'){
        DO = this.select(selector);
    }else if(selector instanceof HTMLElement){
        DO = selector;
    }

    this.children = function children(selector){
        return DO.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    }
    return {
        MF: ???
    }
}(null);
```

I might be wrong in my reflections but what I've come to figure out is that in order to have additional methods for a document object ( html element ) I either need to extend the HTMLElement prototype or pass the element along with my class. I've chosen the second option. I just can't figure out what to return in my class so that  I can have chaining going on. What I simply aim at, for the sake of this example, is to be able to write the following line of code:

```
MF('someDiv').children('someClass');
```

In a desperate attempt I tried returning a new instance of `MF` which should not have instances by default and led myself to an infinite loop. I really cannot figure what I'm supposed to return there. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: `MF('someDiv')` should return an object and methods which don't return anything else (unlike `.children`) should return `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you also tried to use the module pattern, and haven't taken advantage of prototypes..

When you want to chain something, you either need to return itself (`this`) within the chainable methods, or return a `new` instance of your *Object*. In the example below I achieve chaining by using new instances (well the *children* looked like it needed to be a list so I did an *Array* of them).

```
var MF = (function () { // module pattern start
    function MF(selector) {
        if (!(this instanceof MF)) return new MF(selector); // always construct
        this.node = null; // expose your DO
        if (typeof selector === 'string') {
            this.node = document.getElementById(selector);
        } else if (selector instanceof HTMLElement) {
            this.node = selector;
        } else {
            throw new TypeError('Illegal invocation');
        }
    }
    MF.prototype = {}; // set up any inheritance
    MF.prototype.select = function (selector) {
        return new MF(document.getElementById(selector)); // returns new instance
    };
    MF.prototype.children = function (selector) {
        var MFs = [],
            nodes = this.node.getElementsByClassName(selector),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
            MFs[i] = new MF(nodes[i]);
        }
        return MFs; // array of items of new instances
    };
    return MF; // pass refence out
}()); // module pattern end
```

Then, for example, you can chain like..

```
MF(document.body).children('answer')[0].children('post-text')[0].node;
```

Comment: Just pure awesomeness. The only thing I don't understand is what's the difference between using the `prototype` and defining the function as `this.function`, because obviously there is.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner if the constructor function would just return a new instance rather than checking wheter `this instanceof MF` or not. Something like function `MF(selector) { return new API(selector); }`. Probably a good idea to also allow `MF(mfObject)`

Comment: @php_nub_qq I second plalx. Take a look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19748323/783743

Comment: @php_nub_qq setting methods in the constructor has the advantage of creating a new closure, meaning you can access `var`iables from the constructor. However it is also a bad thing because this means you're creating identical functions multiple times, consuming memory. Using a prototype means all instances share the same functions on the prototype.

Answer (score 2):

`return this;` will allow access to methods of the Constructor. Do it at the very bottom of the Constructor and the very bottom inside every method that belongs to it, if the method doesn't need to return another value.

```
function MF(selector){
  var doc = document;
  this.select = function(selector){
    return doc.getElementById(selector);
  }
  // there are problems with some of your code
  this.someMethod = function(){
    /* do stuff - If you want to access an Element then
      var thisIsNowGlobal = this.select('someId');
      thisIsNowGlobal.innerHTML = 'someText';
      Note, the keyword this is global not var
      If you wrote this.select('someId').innerHTML the property would not exist

      When a property of an Object is assigned to a variable or argument
      the this value changes to the global context.
   */
    return this;
  }
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Constructor functions in JavaScript return `this` by default if you don't explicitly return an object. I think you meant to `return this` from methods which don't return anything else. See my comment above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747998/javascript-object-return-itself-a-k-a-chaining#comment29344898_19747998

Comment: I don't understand, if I return `this` in the method `select`, how am I supposed to grab a hold of the HTML element?

Comment: @php_nub_qq: you'd need to do something like jQuery does and places them as a property of the result of calling `MF`.

Comment: if I put `return this` at the bottom, like you have, what I get returned is the window object :/ I suppose that's because I don't have an instance, but how can I return a singleton object?

Comment: @php_nub_qq in regards to your last question. If you want the HTML Element itself, you should assign your object.property to a variable, so the this returns to the global context.

Comment: @php_nub_qq That's because your `this` pointer is not set correctly.

Comment: @AaditMShah if I put the `new` keyword before `MF('someDiv')` I get the correct return, but I aim at not using `new`. Can it really be that hard :/

Comment: @php_nub_qq I'll write an answer to address all of your concerns.

Comment: Read comment in someMethod.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily. Bear in mind that when you `return this` then if `this` has methods defined on it, then you can call them sequentially.

```
var MyUtilThing = function(){};
MyUtilThing.prototype.doStuff = function doStuff (){ // give it a name, helps in debugging
  // do your thing
  console.log('doing stuff');
  return this; // this is your instance of MyUtilThing
}

var thing = new MyUtilThing();
thing.doStuff().doStuff().doStuff(); // etc
```

One way around having to explicitly create instances is do this in your constructor.

```
var MyUtilThing = function(selector){
  var F = function(){};
  F.prototype = MyUtilThing.prototype;
  var toReturn = new F();
  toReturn.initialize(selector);
  return toReturn;
};

MyUtilThing.prototype.initialize = function initialize(selector){
  this.selector = selector;
};

MyUtilThing.prototype.doStuff = function doStuff (){ // give it a name, helps in debugging
  // do your thing
  console.log('doing stuff to', this.selector);
  return this; // this is your instance created in the constructor (the blank function with the same prototype as MyUtilThing)
}

var thing = MyUtilThing('div'); // no use of new here!
thing.doStuff().doStuff().doStuff(); // etc
```

But, getting into some slightly heavy territory there. Best bet is just to try and understand exactly how `this` is used in JS, and you'll get a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally the way jQuery enables chaining is by creating a wrapper object for every type of return value. For example in your case it pays to create your own wrapper for `HTMLElement`:

```
function HTMLElementWrapper(element) {
    if (element instanceof HTMLElementWrapper) return element;
    this.element = element;
}
```

Now that you have an `HTMLElementWrapper` you can refactor your `MF` function as follows:

```
function MF(selector) {
    return new HTMLElementWrapper(typeof selector === "string" ?
        document.getElementById(selector) : selector);
}
```

The `MF` function now returns an `HTMLElementWrapper` object which has two methods `select` and `children`:

```
HTMLElementWrapper.prototype.select = function (selector) {
    return new HTMLElementWrapper(this.element.getElementById(selector));
};

HTMLElementWrapper.prototype.children = function (selector) {
    return new NodeListWrapper(this.element.getElementsByClassName(selector));
};
```

Ofcourse for the `children` function to work you'll need to create a `NodeListWrapper` constructor:

```
function NodeListWrapper(list) {
    if (list instanceof NodeListWrapper) return list;
    this.list = list;
}
```

Now you can chain methods as follows:

```
MF("someDiv").select("something").children("someClass");
```

To chain methods after `.children("someClass")` you need to add those methods to `NodeListWrapper.prototype`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. So you mean to tell me that jquery has wrappers for all DOM objects? `O.o`

Comment: @php_nub_qq I'm don't exactly know what jQuery has but I know that it wraps up HTML elements in custom objects.